# Detecting browser loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, loading

I was just wondering about this, and I haven't found a good answer so far, so I thought I'd just ask it here.

What I'm wondering is, if it's possible to detect browser loading actions. And just to be clear, I'm not talking specificly AJAX request nor the initial loading of the page.

I'm talking about everything the browser loads, so IFrames, jQuery loads, requests.
I know that AJAX requests are detectable, but as for image loading, or IFrames not so much.

And I'd like for this to be as dynamic as possible, ie. nothing added to the DOM structure whatsoever.

Well, that's it really, I thought that this would be an interesting thingy. 
Anyway, thanks for reading and have a nice day. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. You can only detect when the browser is done loading or when it is starting to unload.
So apart from those events, there's nothing really you can use to detect that the browser is busy.

As long as the browser is busy loading/unloading, it will not execute any custom javascripts.